# What's a simple language to use for creating graphics?

Tags: graphics, 3d, programming-languages, data-visualization

What is a rapid coding language or platform for quickly creating data visualization images in 2d and 3d?

I want to rapidly code up visualizations like this:
http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc

I already know how to code OpenGL and DirectX, but those environments are built for rendering speed not coding speed.

To try out many different ideas I don't care if the language is interpreted or slower to render - just the ability to get things on screen in a short amount of time for prototyping.

Maybe even a graphics language for kids would work - or not, I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is processing, http://processing.org/ which allow quick and dirty code to visualize data. Mostly used by researchers not viable in production. It is written in java. I had a terrible time with it so I am not really fond of it.

Otherwise, you can use python and GraphViz for 2d graph, http://www.graphviz.org/. Python allows really fast development with an easy learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but an interesting one. I think a Javascript based data visualization library would fit the requirements very nicely. It's a scripting language making it appropriate for fast prototyping, and your code will basically work anywhere with a browser.

There are numerous Javascript libraries for data visualization, I personally recommend [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), as you can see from the demos, they have several charts very similar to the ones linked in this question. [This one](http://labs.vis4.net/parteispenden/), for example, was built with the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) Javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

How about [processing](http://processing.org/)?